# Script to substract date time format to get result in hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two cell that have time and date in this format "9/12/2021 10:41:571".

I need help with writing a function that will return the difference of both the timestamp in hours

Answer (score 0):

As long as your date/times are formatted as numbers rather than text, you could subtract them from each other then multiply by 24:

```
=(A2-A1)*24
```

Comment: I tried that, Im not getting the right result. https://imgur.com/a/czgv352

Comment: In your example, there is 1 minute between the date/times. 1/60 = 0.0166666667 hrs. What are you expecting instead? if you want it formatted as hh:mm, the don't multiple by 24, and use the format menu to specify hh:mm

Answer (score 0):

*If the number of hours does not exceed `24`*, you can also use the following formulae:

```
=HOUR(A3-A2)
=MINUTE(A3-A2)
=SECOND(A3-A2)
=CONCATENATE(B2," hour/s ",C2," minute/s, ",D2," second/s")
```

Therefore, assuming that your two dates are located in the `A2` and `A3` cells, the formulae above will calculate the difference between the two returning the *hours*, *minutes* and *seconds*.

**Spreadsheet**

[image: spreadsheet with the formulae]

#### Reference

- [HOUR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093045);
- [MINUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093048);
- [SECOND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093054);
- [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123).